# jQuery ASP.NET find a particular CheckBox in  a CheckBoxList by the innerHTML of the CheckBox Label

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET CheckBoxList:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" Width="10%">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="1">White</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="False" Value="2">Black</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Red</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Green</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="5">Blue</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

I need to modify/delete a particular label of a particular CheckBox in a CheckBoxList:

The following code is working fine for the CheckBox value, however it is not working for the CheckBox label.

```
var CheckBoxListInputValue = 3; //value may be dynamic
var CheckBoxListInputInnerHTML = "Red"; //value may be dynamic
$("#CheckBoxList1 label[innerHTML =" + CheckBoxListInputInnerHTML + "]").remove(); //Not working
$("#CheckBoxList1 :input[value = " + CheckBoxListInputValue + "]").remove(); //Working
```

BTW, I don't want to use any for loop.

Answer (score 1):

asp.net generate a table from your checkboxlist, and in order to remove an option you must remove actually a TR. The following code remove the Red option on your sample then you can change Red with the dynamic value

```
  $('#CheckBoxList1 label').each(function () {
        if ($(this).text() == 'Red') {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

[Test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/wDWst/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `:contains` selector:

```
$("#CheckBoxList1 label:contains(" + CheckBoxListInputInnerHTML + ")").remove();
```

<sub>please note that `:input` selector is *deprecated*, you can use `input` instead.</sub>